# How can I move one of two perfectly identical rows into a new table through a query?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

MS SQL Server 2008

I Use following Query to filter duplicate rows into a single row

Query 1 - `SELECT DISTINCT * FROM flatfile_old`

But now i want to move those query results into a new table and i try following things

Query 2 - `SELECT * INTO flatfile_new FROM Flatfile_old WHERE 1 = 2`

Query 3 - `INSERT INTO flatfile_new (SELECT DISTINCT * FROM flatfile_old)`

But Query No 3 throws error like follows

> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 1 Incorrect syntax near the keyword
>   'select'. Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1 Incorrect syntax near
>   ')'.

Please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just remove the brackets `( ... )` like this:

```
INSERT INTO flatfile_new 
SELECT DISTINCT * FROM flatfile_old
```